# Camera2 Saved image is blurry

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am working on creating my own Camera2 application. I am new to this and still learning.

I based all of my code of off [Google's Github page](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).

My code has been uploaded to Github and can be viewed [here](https://github.com/MatthewRidenhour/Android_camera2_image/blob/copyGoogle/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/cameratest/MainActivity.java)

My code is different from googles because I am creating an Activity and Google's example is using a Fragment.

The issue I am having is that my current code will save a very blurry JPEG.

I've looked over my code and compared it to Google's code, and I cannot find what I'm doing different.

Here is a picture of what it is being saved on my app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your texture view section. I think that is where you went wrong